# For-in looping through an object stops after first key

Tags: javascript, iteration, for-in-loop

Can someone explain how to iterate over all of an object's key-val pairs? Do I need to add the stringified pairs into a new object, then return that object? So far, I've got the following, which works for nested objects, but it'll only return the first pair.

```
var objectify = function (obj, stringifyJSON) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty) {
                return (stringifyJSON(key) + ":" + stringifyJSON(obj[key]));
            }
```

As it is, for an object like {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3 }, I'm getting back just {"a": 1}.

I've also tried the following:

```
var objectify = function (obj, stringify) {
    var holder = {};
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty) {
                holder[stringifyJSON(key)] = stringifyJSON(obj[key]);
            }
        }
        return ("" + holder + "");
    };
```

which just returns {[object Object]}. I've tried assigning the key and value with quotes and without calling stringify on the key and value, but those both return {[object Object]} as well.

Here's the snippet that calls objectify:

```
else if (typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null) {
    return ("{" + objectify(obj, stringifyJSON) + "}");
}
```

Comment: What is the end result you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to give me back a string containing the object, with each pair in it also stringified. l2mt's answer (pointing out that I need the holder var to be a string, not an object) is basically what I was looking for.

Comment: @ Steve: "A string containing the object" is quite vague. I'm glad l2mt was able to help! Links for next time, so you get better answers more quickly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask \* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use return in the loop.
A possible solution could be:

```
var objectify = function (obj, stringifyJSON) {
     var tmp = '';
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty) {
                tmp  = tmp + (stringifyJSON(key) + ":" + stringifyJSON(obj[key]));
                tmp =+ '; '; // here you can put any char that you want to separate objects
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Would you mind elaborating on the =+ thing? I'm getting back {NaN}.

Comment: Sorry, is += or better use => tmp = tmp + ';';